# Finding Line Tangent to $g(x^2)$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

At $x=9$, the equation of the tangent line to the graph of $y=g(x)$ is 
$$2x+11y=-37$$ 
What is the equation of the tangent line to $y=g(x^2)$ at $x=3$ and the equation of the tangent line to $y=(g(x))^2$ at $x=9$?

Please help guys, I've been trying to figure this out for an hour and no success.. I really appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: If you've been working at it for an hour, then  you must have some work to show. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to the [Chain Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)!

The derivative of $y=g(x^2)$ is $y'=2x*g(x^2)$,

and the derivative of $y=(g(x))^2$ is $y'=2*g(x)*g'(x)$.

Hopefully you can solve from here.